# Full remove Eclipse

Tags: 13.10, eclipse

I have installed Eclipse 3.8 from the terminal in Ubuntu 13.10, but 
I can't open it from the Launcher. The command: `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= eclipse` can open it, but I cannot install Windows Builder plug-in, and it shows this message: `Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.` I also cannot install Android. so what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you start eclipse from the terminal? Just type `eclipse` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

To FULLY remove Eclipse, I'd rather use the `purge`- instead of the `remove`-command: `sudo apt-get purge eclipse`. To directly reinstall it, use `sudo apt-get purge --reinstall eclipse`

Comment: I can't install windows-builder plug-in and have this message "cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found"

Answer (score 0):

try this command : `apt-get remove eclipse`